# didReceiveRemoteNotification and Banner Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, event-handling, push-notification

I want to do Banner Notification during game play.

Not Alert

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{    
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
        NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.alertBody = message;
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
}
```

UILocalNotification is not working during game play

How to operate the banner?? What's Problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =0;
    localNotification.alertBody =message;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Make sure, you have enabled the notification in iPhone->Settings->Notifications,
local notification (as well as push notification) will not be shown if your application is currently open.

Answer (score 0):

The notification alert type cannot be set by developer. Only user can set in iOS's setting menu.